# How to format a number into decimal in php

Tags: php

I have the below simple number, `$total = 1060;`, that i need to format as below using PHP

> 10.60

**What i tried**

```
$total = 1060;
number_format($total, 2)
```

But the result showing is `1,060.00` instead of the below `10.60`

Plus I need it to be a dot `.` and not a comma `,` as the separator

Comment: From what I remember from the math classes in school, `1060` is 100 times bigger than `10.60`. [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) knows how to do it, if you provide it the correct value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is divide by 100 in before you format it. That makes it `10.6` (because the second decimal is zero, it's not needed and stripped away), and then you format it to have two decimal places.

```
$total = 1060;
number_format($total/100, 2); // 10.60
```

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/IqU00)